# How to Use TabBarViewController with a NavigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I know I can do this

```
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.someUITabBarController animated:YES];
```

And that means putting `UITabBarController` on a `navigationgController` somehow

What about if I want `someUITabBarController` to be the first controller (the one located on the lowest level) of `navigationController`?

I simply cannot change the `rootViewController` of the `NavigationController` into `someUITabBarController`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Erm not sure this is what you want. Below this code will be put under the `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` in you "appDelegate" class.

```
UITabBarController *tabController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
UIViewController *viewController1 = ...
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController1];

NSArray *controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navigationController, nil]; // can add more if you want

[tabController setViewControllers:controllers];

// this is for custom title and image in the tabBar item
navigationController.tabBarItem.title = @"abc";
[navigationController.tabBarItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"abc.png"]];

self.window.rootViewController = tabController; // or [self.window addSubview: tabController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this works. But try this,

```
UINavigationController *navCont = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
[navCont pushViewController:navCont animated:NO];
```